# How to detect if a Bash environment variable has been read?

Tags: bash, metadata, environment-variables

I have a script that is supplied with configuration via environment variables. Because the configuration is manually edited it is possible for typos and variables that are never used to be added to the configuration.

Is there a way to obtain meta-data about a variable that would allow for a post-execution step to warn if a variable had not be read?

Acceptable answers include,

- A way to count how many times a var has been read
- A flag that is true if the var has been read
- A way to determine the last time the var was accessed

There may be other acceptable answers that are not listed above.

This problem has arisen in part because Bash by default is untyped.

Comment: So since "no, there's nothing like that" isn't "acceptable, I'll leave that in a comment. The usual way of dealing with this is the opposite. Your script/program should verify all its parameters (wherever they come from) before it starts.

Comment: @Mat - thanks. Pre-execution verification is being added but I am looking for a more sweeping way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions in your post. First question:

> How to detect if a Bash environment variable has been read?

Even though none of the acceptable answers include mine, I will answer the first question for the benefit of others:

Nohow, except modifying Bash.

You're free to reject it of course.

Second question:

> Is there a way to obtain meta-data about a variable that would allow for a post-execution step to warn if a variable had not be read?

Asking this question doesn't make much sense, since the possible answers are not included in the acceptable answer list. But I'll answer it anyway:

No, except if Bash is modified.

Now, even though you might be uninterested in my opinion as it is not within the list of acceptable answers, I'm going to present it anyway as an exercise for me and maybe useful information for others.

First of all, making a warning in this case is mostly useless, especially after the execution. Whatever mistakes were made in providing parameters, they have already taken effect by that time, be it corrupted data or simply time lost. Moreover, most people will not take notice of warnings if in their opinion the result of the script's work is OK. They might find they were wrong later, but it might be too late.

If you're going to validate parameters, do that *before* execution and *abort* if they're wrong.

One way to ensure that there are no typos in the environment variable names is to create a namespace for them by requiring that their names are prefixed with a fixed string and then verifying that all the variable names having that prefix are known to the program. However, that doesn't protect from typos in the prefix string. Still, no other program that I know of does that and that likely means that hardly anyone expects such behavior from a program. This violates the "rule of least surprise" and, I'd say, unnecessarily so.

I would suggest to not validate the environment variable names at all. If your program has complex configuration, which requires validation, don't put it into the environment. Put it into a configuration file, which would not be shared with other programs.

One easy way to do that is to make configuration file a sourced shell script
which sets a bunch of variables. This would allow easy "parsing" (as Bash
will do it), and validation. To validate it, source it in a subshell
(so the main shell is not affected), output names of variables that are set,
filtering out variables which were set before sourcing, then compare them to
the list of known configuration variable names.

Something like this:

```
function list_vars() {
    declare -p | awk -F'[ =]' '/^declare/ {print $3}'
}

function unset_vars() {
    while read v; do
        unset "$v" 2>/dev/null;
    done < <(list_vars);
}

declare -a CONF_VAR_NAMES=(FOO BAR BAZ)

extra_vars=`
    (
        # Unset all variables that can be unset (and thus set)
        unset_vars
        # List variables set after sourcing configuration
        (. conf_file.sh; list_vars) |
            # Remove variables set before sourcing
            grep -v -F -f <(list_vars)
    ) |
        # Remove known variables
        grep -v -F -f <(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${CONF_VAR_NAMES[*]}")
`

if [ -n "$extra_vars" ]; then
    echo "Unknown variables set by configuration script: $extra_vars" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

You may want special handling for PATH and other important variables, though.
It may be a good idea to simply set all variables read-only before sourcing,
when validating.

Comment: This is a very useful answer and I will certainly not exclude it from the list of candidate acceptable answers. It seems that I need to find a different way of providing examples of what will be acceptable in order to not discourage potentially valuable contributions.